# Using Dropbox's python API to detect changes

Tags: python, dropbox

How would I go about detecting if a file changed, using Dropbox's python API?  I can't simply check the file on disk because it won't be updated if it's in use.

Comment: See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#longpoll-delta, and https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#delta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use the files hash that you get from the Metadata call of the API. You should then store this hash locally.

The Metadata API call can also take a metadata parameter which will make it return a 304 (Not Modified) status if the file has not changed. (more info: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#metadata)

But this method still requires you to poll the API constantly.